# Linker error: cannot link to '&.obj'

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I am trying to compile a qt project under windows (it builds just fine on linux), but keep getting uncomprehensible linker error:

```
    link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.8.4\lib" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"debug\LPR_Demo.intermediate.manifest" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /OUT:debug\LPR_Demo.exe @C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\LPR_Demo.exe.1936.4150.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '&.obj'
```

I have no idea what &.obj might be and why in the world linker would need it. Googling gives me notheing on the subject.

How could i resolve this situation?

Comment: what's the command used to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use back slashes in your .pro file.  Switch them to forward slashes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ...i cannot believe it. That worked. (and adding some more empty lines).